# PHP не работает Post

Tags: php

Параметры с формы должный отправляться методом post в функцию, а функция должна записывать данные с формы в csv файл.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="SecondName" placeholder="Second Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="mark" placeholder="Mark"><br>
        <button>Send</button>
</form>

function putCsv() {
$file = 'csv.csv';
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
$val = fputcsv($fp, $_POST['mark']);
fclose($fp);
return $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fputcsv` ожидает передачи массива в качестве второго аргумента. 
Вот, посмотрите пример.

```php
<?php
?>
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="SecondName" placeholder="Second Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="mark" placeholder="Mark"><br>
        <button>Send</button>
</form>
<?php
?>
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="SecondName" placeholder="Second Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="mark" placeholder="Mark"><br>
        <button>Send</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SecondName'])){
    $secondName = $_POST['SecondName'];
} else {
    $secondName = "";
}
if(isset($_POST['mark'])){
    $mark = $_POST['mark'];
} else {
    $mark = "";
}
if($mark){
    $params = array(
        "SecondName"=>$secondName,
        "mark"=>$mark
    );
    putCsv($params);
}

function putCsv($c) {
    $file = 'csv.csv';
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    $val = fputcsv($fp, $c);
    fclose($fp);
    return $val;
}
```